# MySQL take 10 time space than the data we upload

Tags: mysql, cpanel

I create 1333 column in mysql. 1332 are empty at the moment, I will upload data later in that. only 1st column has data.

I upload 2.5 GB of data but it took almost 30 GB space.

333 Clumn typeis date
500 are VARCHAR(50)
500 are INT(25) (approx)

is there any way I can make column*row data null and it take less space?

[image]

PS: I am using cpanel

Comment: *is there any way I can make column*row data null and it take less space?* No, I think. `DATE` and `INT` occupies the space anycase, even when the values are NULL. Plus `VARCHAR` which occupies at least 2 bytes, plus inner row index, plus reserve block space and block header.. PS. `INT(25)` makes no sense: 1. INT cannot store 25 digits, only up to 10; 2) Length specifying is anycase ignored.

Comment: That is a horrible table design. That is not how you should work with SQL databases at all.

Answer (score -1):

You have to normalize your DB Structure. This one looks like a blank excel sheet. You should try to avoid these null fields and keep in mind not to save redundant data.